# Different color being display in div

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm having issues with this div.
I have my css assigning a white backgound color.
This is [demo](http://jsbin.com/xucit/1) of the issue

```
div.bonecardLightBox {
    background-color: white;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1001;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 850px;
    height: 525px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    float: center;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

But unfortunately I'm seeing a gray color.Still don't know why.

This is an image of how the image looks.
[image]

Comment: Could you please post the html too? Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: I added to the question: Is this one: http://jsbin.com/xucit/1

Comment: Are you meaning the grey colour which comes from the embedded github gist?

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, AND in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `<body>` has an `opacity:0.75;` this will affect all elements

Easyest way out of this, set a transparent picture as background to your `<body>`:

```
background-image:url(/path/to/transparent/1px-1px.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
```

Then it will not affect all other elements. You could do it with css only but it's a hack with positioning and wan't even work in all older browsers.

Comment: Darn it, beat me to it!

Comment: @JosefE. verry lucky :-)

Comment: While `rgba` won't work with older browsers, there's no reason to call it a hack. What hack do you have in mind?

Comment: @JanDvorak the hack I have in mind is creating a relative positioned div with an an absolute and relative positioned div inside where one of them gets the opacity.. so that's kind of a hack which doesn't works everywhere.. but you are right, maybe I shouldn't have called it a hack

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is one thing, but it isn't a complete solution.

You should add to your CSS also:

```
div.gist-data {
  background-color: #fff !important; 
}
```

to make colour white